# cpanel paper_lantern takes too long to load

Tags: javascript, cpanel, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Most of my shared hosting accounts have changed theme from X3 to paper_lantern. However, I find the paper_lantern theme takes way longer to load - often 15-to-20 seconds before the page is fully displayed. During this time, the GENERAL INFORMATION side panel will have a loading spinner beside the THEME item, so I suspect that is somehow involved in the delay.

In DevTools, the network tab has a bunch of entries like below image which, when added up, account for almost the entire wait time.

Does anyone know of a way, perhaps using GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey or AdBlock(?), to abort whatever process is happening here and just get on with displaying the CPANEL panels/icons?

(Browser in use is Google Chrome)

[image: CPANEL Paper_Lantern theme delays]

Comment: In DevTools you could right-click on the request you want to block, and select the option `Block request URL`. You might need to enable some experimental option for that. (Assuming *Chrome*)

Comment: Something is wrong with your installation and/or web host.  My cPanel, `paper_lantern` theme, loads (cacheless) in about 4 seconds. It only requests 8 or 9 scripts, and only requests `index.live.php?act=top` once. ... Anywho, what you request can be devilishly difficult (impossible without an MCVE) on all modern browsers.  Although it's much easier (for the next few months only) on Firefox ESR.  We need an MCVE or access to your cPanel.